# How do you calculate past cron jobs schedules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I would like to be able to find the times a cron job would have ran given the cron string. For example, with `0 */5 * * * *`, the job runs every five minutes. If it is 13:02, the next job is at 13:05 and the last job was at 13:00. If there is a library out there that does this, I would like to use that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider using [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser), this allows you to determine previous and future cron times from a cron expression.

For example:

```
const parser = require('cron-parser');

const options = {
  currentDate: new Date('2020-06-25T13:02:00Z'),
  iterator: true
};

const interval = parser.parseExpression('0 */5 * * * *', options);

console.log("Previous run:", interval.prev().value.toISOString());
console.log("Next run:", interval.next().value.toISOString());
```

You should see something like:

```
 Previous run: 2020-06-25T13:00:00.000Z
 Next run: 2020-06-25T13:05:00.000Z
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Later.js](http://bunkat.github.io/later/)!

From the documentation:

```js
// fires at 10:15am every day
var cron = '0 */5 * * * *';
var s = later.parse.cron(cron);

later.schedule(s).next(10);
// gets you the next 10 times the cron expression will run

later.schedule(s).prev(10);
// gets you the last 10 times the cron expression ran
```